# create a query and put the result into datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've got a table

```
idteacher idstudent idsubject studentname subjectname teacherame mark
```

But how to fill it with information from tables

```
idteacher teachername
idstudent studentname
idsubject subjectname
```

and `mark` - field which exists only in this table and then put it into datagrid?(I've already created datagrid and table(in visual studio->Server explorer))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the following tables in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
    idteacher int,
    teachername nchar(50))

CREATE TABLE student (
    idstudent int,
    studentname nchar(50))

CREATE TABLE subject (
    idsubject int,
    subjectname nchar(50))

CREATE TABLE mark (
    idteacher int,
    idstudent int,
    idsubject int,
    mark int)
```

I've ommited the primary and foreign keys for brevity. You would then retrieve the data for your `DataGrid` with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    t.idteacher,
    st.idstudent,
    s.idsubject,
    t.teachername,
    st.studentname,
    s.subjectname,
    m.mark
FROM mark m
    INNER JOIN teacher t ON m.idteacher = t.idteacher
    INNER JOIN student st ON m.idstudent = st.idstudent
    INNER JOIN subject s ON m.idsubject = s.idsubject
```

To load the data into the `DataGrid` use Denys's `GetData()` method with the above query.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to bind data from a SQL table to a ASP.NET gridview if yes than it can be done like this:

**Code behind:**

```
    public System.Data.DataTable GetData()
    {
        System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
        string connectionString =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("GetCars", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        return table;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridView.DataSource = GetData();
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
```

**Web.config** - for security and to allow for easy switching between different databases store the connection string in the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Your connection string..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCars
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Cars
    ORDER BY CarId DESC
END
```

Whether you should use inline SQL statements or stored procedures has always been a very controversial subject, but from personal experience I would agree with Marc and using them has the following advantages:

1. SP's are pre-compiled for faster performance
2. Reduces surface area of attack for SQL injection
3. Allows you to abstract complex data processing from the application

Comment: You should wrap `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(...) { ... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal .... also: **never** use `SELECT * ...` in production code.

Comment: @marc_s thank you for the advice, I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Set the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedatalist.datasource.aspx) property of the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) to the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) you should load.